# Security measures - when and how

Tags: php, mysql, security, web-applications

Currently I am upgrading a web application in which I will get most of the input from logged in users. The input will contains valid html, images, audio, video & upload facilities to user defined path. The application then formats it into nice ui and displays to end users. These privileged users can add / modify / delete the content using a web based interface.

As per the basic rule of thumb: I should escape my data before entering in DB, and not to receive data receive from user. To achieve that I have planned to follow following security measures. Which also includes my questions

1. I am using prepared statements to store all user inputs to DB. I hope this eliminates the DB injection threat.

   - Is this measure enough? or do i need to check for % and _ symbols as well for mysql `LIKE` queries?
2. The user input (lets call input A), where I am not expecting any HTML/css, I use `strip_tags` & `htmlentities` before inserting in DB.

   - Is this adequate measure ? Should I be using more
3. The user input (lets call input B), in which user can have html/css tags, I user `htmlentities` on text then insert in DB.

   - As far as I am aware I should not use `htmlentities` before inserting in the DB, but have to as previous programmer was using it. Are there any negative impacts for this?
4. After fetching from DB and Before displaying the input A / input B , I am not doing any pre processing assuming, the data added to DB should be clean.

   - Should i process / sanitize the data before displaying ? If yes then how ?
5. I want to html tags enters by user to be parsed by browser and not displayed to user. e.g. if user had entered `<p style='color:red;'>hello</p><p class='noclass'>world</p>`, I want user to see 2 words only and not actual text.

   - To achieve this how can I make sure that user doesn't add malicious script and at the same time the html tags are stored, fetched and parsed by browser correctly.

Please guide if the current approach is sufficient / not sufficient / less / incorrect.
I am neither a 100% newbie to php nor I m pro. I know the basics about php (or we can say over all web applications') security. So can someone can please guide me if I am making any mistake security wise OR should not be doing something OR should be doing something more or less.

I know the basics of security but I still get confused over

- Which exact security measure to apply at which exact point ? (e.g. escape string BEFORE inserting to DB)
- At every point what the functions available in php? (e.g. to escape strings use prepared statements)

Comment: Just to notice that the first goal of prepared statements is not to prevent SQL injections but really helpful.

Comment: @Debflav. Yes I fully agree. It helps to create DB independent applications. But i have always used mysql and it helps me escaping data as well.

Comment: For '5' you can use a [sanitizer in combination with a Content Security Policy](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/49342/8340).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, prepared statements are great at preventing SQL injections problems. Yes, you will have to take care of `%` and `_` in `LIKE` queries, a prepared statement cannot escape them since it has no way to know whether you *want* those values there or not.
2. through 5.: It's always a bad idea to escape data going into the database for a format it's destined for on output. Why? First of all, why are you so sure you're always going to use the data in an HTML context? Maybe you'll be using it in a different format in the future, and then you'll have garbage looking data. (This is more hypothetical in your case, as you're explicitly storing HTML.)

   Secondly though, your output code will have to rely on your input code to correctly have escaped data in advance, possibly with a long time between input and output. Your output code can have no confidence whatsoever that the input code did the correct job for what the output code needs it to do. Therefore, escaping for output must happen at the time of output. No sooner, no later.

   Thirdly (is that a word?), `strip_tags` is absolutely insufficient to accept some HTML but not other "insecure" HTML. You need a more complex library which has more complex whitelisting rules than what `strip_tags` can do. Supposedly the only library that does that is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org). I'd run all user HTML through it.

To summarise:

1. Prepared statements.
2. HTML-escape data that is not supposed to contain literal HTML **on output**.
3. Run any data that is supposed to contain literal HTML through HTML Purifier. Whether you do this before or after inserting to the database is up to you, depending on whether you want to store the literal input the user sent you or whether you don't mind discarding that original data immediately and storing only sanitised data instead. But, the same caveat about having confidence in your output code applies too.

Comment: Thank you for quick and detailed answer. What is the best way to securely (is sanitize a proper word to use?) display the user given input with html tags (option 3)?

Comment: I thought I answered that question with *HTML Purifier*...? If data is not supposed to contain HTML, then escape it (`htmlspecialchars`), which removes any special HTML meaning. If it *is* supposed to contain HTML, then sanitise that HTML to make sure it contains no malicious code (HTML Purifier).

Comment: my apologies... i wasn't clear enough. I should have asked what is the way to secure the data WITHOUT additional library? I mean how to do it with pure php functions (can i be sure it must have been done before) ?

Comment: There's no secure way to sanitise HTML built into PHP as far as I'm aware.